# Issue with ofstream class instance not compiling

Tags: c++, iostream, ofstream, file-writing

I'm encountering an issue with writing to a file using ofstream within a C++ class. I've created a minimal example to illustrate the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Aclass {
private:
    std::ofstream historyFile;

public:
    Aclass() {
        historyFile.open("test.txt");

        if (!historyFile.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Unable to open file for writing: test.txt" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void writeFile() const {
        historyFile << "sometext";
        historyFile.close();
    }

    void writeFile2() const{
        std::ofstream ofs ("test.txt");
        ofs << "sometext";
        ofs.close();
    }
};

int main() {
    Aclass instance;
    instance.writeFile();
    std::cout << "Finished writing to file" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`writeFile` complains

**no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: const std::ofstream << const char [9]**

and

**the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::close [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" -- object type is: const std::ofstream**

for the subsequent line

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0

Why does the second implementation compile and run and not the first?  It seems like both should be equivalent?

Comment: It tells you what's wrong (in a slightly obscure way). You can't write to a `const` stream.

Comment: By removing const from writeFile(), it seems to compile and work.  Why does it work for writeFile2 which is also const?

Comment: Is it your classmate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77054929/vector-wont-let-me-modify-contents-but-it-isnt-const

Comment: In `writeFile()` you try to modify the member variable, but the function is marked as `const` meaning it can't modify member variable. The  `writeFile2` function doesn't attempt to modify member variables.

Comment: `const` on a function means all member variables pretend to be `const`. `ofs` is not a member variable, so it's not affected.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you guys for the quick response!  I that explains it all!

Comment: The member function `close()` in `historyFile.close()` is not a `const` function (since it changes state of `historyFile`).   `historyFile` is a member of `Aclass`, so its non-`const` member functions cannot be called from a `const` member of `Aclass`.    The error message is telling you that, albeit with an additional flood of technical detail.

Comment: Aside:  From a design perspective, it is probably not a good idea for `Aclass::writeFile()` to close `historyFile` - since (removing the `const` qualifier will allow that to happen), calling it twice will try to write to a closed stream.